# Getting weird error in system.log after fresh installation of Magento CE 1.7.0.2 related to GeoIP

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

After a fresh installation of Magento CE 1.7.0.2, I am getting a 404 Page not found on localhost/index.php and localhost/index.php/admin. I enabled debugging in index.php and I am getting the following log over and over (every time I refresh the page):

2014-08-01T14:49:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): GEOIP::COUNTRY::APPFR

2014-08-01T14:49:38+00:00 DEBUG (7): GEOIP::CONTINENT::APPEU

Notice the "APP" before the "FR" (for France)? I have no idea how I am getting this error.

By the way, i installed the GeoIP extension after I built a Ubuntu 14.0.2 VM with LAMP installation (PHP 5.5.9 and MySQL 5.5.38). The weird thing is the GeoIP extension didn't come with PHP5.5, I had to install it separately (apt-get install php5-geoip) in order to be able to install the database through Magento Installation Wizard.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was due to an error in the source code. After a fresh new installation with new code, the problem is gone.